# React/Redux - Set a load spinner to Item in a list. Send component as parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using React with Redux. I have a list of items.

- The list is one component **ItemsTable**.
- Every item on the list is an instance of **Item** component.
- Every **Item** have a form to update via an action that uses ajax to PUT.

I want to set a spinner to the Item form, while we wait for the ajax response.
First I set a fetching state to my store like *fetching: True.* Then I use a conditional rendering to render the more spin. But since this state is not individual for each Item component, all items in the list render the spinner.

After that, I tried other solution. On the item action, I send the component (this) as a parameter. Then, I also include the component in the payload to the reducer and there I set a fetching state for the component, not for the store.

It works quite well, but I am not sure that it is the best practice. What is the best way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use your first approch, but add to the reducer the key/index of the item. Key is better because index can change. Then, when you map your Items in ListItems, add condition to check if current Item is equal to saved item from the reducer, if so, render spinner instead.